# Re-Calculating number of Years, Months, and Days Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query returns  this result :

| EmpNo | EmpName | Years | Months | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Ahmed | 0 | 14 | 39 |

In this case, I have 14 months, so it should add one year in the **years field** and remains 2
months in **months field**, and I have 39 days, so it should add one month in the **months field** and remains 9 days in **days field**

how I could re-calculate the  years, months, and days to get query result like this :

| EmpNo | EmpName | Years | Months | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Ahmed | 1 | 2 | 9 |

Comment: Perhaps you should start with some date, like 1-1-1970, and add all your bits to it (like add months 14), then pull the difference between the result and jan 1 1970 and extract the bits.. thing is, the result could vary thanks to the months bit because a month is a variable number of days long(there is a different number of days between 1 jan and 1 feb vs 1 feb and 1 mar). If it's eg "length of service" you should probably use start date (if known) if you cannot tolerate the approximation

Comment: As of your "39 days" explanation: does it mean that in this *problem* all months have 30 days?

Comment: not all cases have 39 days ,may less or more

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you could provide where your data comes from so we can suggest an e2e solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but it is more correct to use the date field:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET
    days = mod(days,30),
    months = mod(months,12) + trunc(days/30),
    years = years + trunc(months/12);

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange to say that all months have 30 days.  But if you are assuming that you need to recalculate all columns.  In this case, revert to days and recalculate everything:

```
select t.*,
       mod(x.total_days, 30) as days,
       floor(mod(x.total_days, 360) / 30) as months,
       floor(mod(x.total_days / 360)) as years
from t cross join lateral
     (select t.days + t.months * 30 + t.years * 360 as total_days
      from dual
     ) x;
```

Note that this handles the case where you have 0/11/39.

If you want this in an `update`, you should be able to use a subquery:

```
update (select t.*, t.days + t.months * 30 + t.years * 360 as total_days
        from t
       ) 
    set days = total_days, 30),
        months = floor(mod(total_days, 360) / 30),
        years = floor(mod(x.total_days / 360));
```

Assuming that a month has 30 days and (hence) that a year has 360 days seems problematic, but that is another issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. However, I think it should be 1 year, 3 months and 9 days though, Kindly let me know otherwise.

```
UPDATE your_table
SET
    days = days - 30,
    months = months + 1
WHERE
    days > 30;

COMMIT;

UPDATE your_table
SET
    months = months - 12,
    years = years + 1
WHERE
    months > 12;

COMMIT;
```

Output:

```
Empno Empname Years Months Days
-------------------------------
  111   Ahmed      1     3    9
```

Comment: Dear i did not ask for updating query

Comment: In that case, just go with a case when.